# Array Index Out of Bounds error Inputting Data

Tags: java, arrays, input, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm trying to input the numbers in a data file into an array. However, I keep I I am getting an array index out of bounds error. Here is the block of code reporting the error.

```
Scanner myIn = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(("Data10.txt")));

for(int x=0; x<n.length; x++)   
    for(int j=0;j<s.length();j++)
    {
      n[x][j] = Character.getNumericValue(s.charAt(j));

    }
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code using a debugger? Netbeans?

Comment: what are `n` and `s`?

Comment: public int readDataInts(int [][]n, String s)
    {
        int max = 0; 
        
      
        try {  n is the 2d array

Comment: Time to learn debugging.

Comment: @RobertDucharmeProbably s lenght is bigger than j so you get this error.

Comment: @erhun That makes no sense. `j` is a counter that counts until `s.length`.

Comment: @m0skit0Check this  public static void main(String[] args) {
  String s = "100043243242323";
  int[][] n = { { 10, 1, 3 }, { 10, 3 } };
  for (int x = 0; x < n.length; x++)
   for (int j = 0; j < s.length(); j++) {
    n[x][j] = Character.getNumericValue(s.charAt(j));
   }
 }

Comment: @erhun You mean s.length() is bigger than n[i].length. Then yes, probably.

Comment: @m0skit0yes we didn't see the code so everythink is possible so i proof it in my code, thanks to you clarify it :)

Answer (score 0):

For `j` index, you want the length of the second dimension of the array, not the length of the string.

```
for(int j=0;j<s.length();j++)
```

should be

```
for(int j=0;j<n[i].length;j++)
```

PS: counters are usually named `i,j,k`, not `x`. [This is an inheritance from Fortran.](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/86904/why-do-most-of-us-use-i-as-a-loop-counter-variable)